# A word or expression to describe someone who don't think for themselves

Tags: vocabulary

People who don't have a critical mind. They repeat what they heard without questioning or analyzing the subject matter. What would you call these kind of individuals??

Thank you .

Comment: Members of the chorus in a Gilbert & Sullivan opera! More seriously, *uncritical* (adj.) or *sheeple* (n., plural, pejorative, slang).

Answer (score 5):

Such a person would be a [*parrot*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/parrot?s=t):

> 2. a person who, without thought or understanding, merely repeats the words or imitates the actions of another.
> 3. to repeat or imitate without thought or understanding.

Though one hears the verb form more often (*he just parrots back what they tell him*).

For a more common noun, there is also the closely related [*sheep*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sheep?s=t):

> 3. a meek, unimaginative, or easily led person.

Answer (score 1):

They can be described as **gullible**, **unsophisticated**, or even slightly **naive**.